# Find a value in an javascript object where the amount of values varies

Tags: javascript

just scratching my head with this one.  How can I extract the time remaining in seconds from the object below? Please note, the number of options varies depending on the program being run, so I somehow need to search for the "value:" associated with the "key:" "BSH.Common.Option.RemainingProgramTime".

```
{
"data": {
    "key": "Dishcare.Dishwasher.Program.Intensiv70",
    "options": [
        {
            "key": "BSH.Common.Option.StartInRelative",
            "value": 0,
            "unit": "seconds"
        },
        {
            "key": "Dishcare.Dishwasher.Option.HalfLoad",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "key": "Dishcare.Dishwasher.Option.IntensivZone",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "key": "Dishcare.Dishwasher.Option.VarioSpeedPlus",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "key": "Dishcare.Dishwasher.Option.SilenceOnDemand",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "key": "BSH.Common.Option.ProgramProgress",
            "value": 82,
            "unit": "%"
        },
        {
            "key": "BSH.Common.Option.RemainingProgramTime",
            "value": 1680,
            "unit": "seconds"
        },
        {
            "key": "BSH.Common.Option.RemainingProgramTimeIsEstimated",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "key": "BSH.Common.Option.EnergyForecast",
            "value": 89,
            "unit": "%"
        },
        {
            "key": "BSH.Common.Option.WaterForecast",
            "value": 70,
            "unit": "%"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `array.find()` to get the object you need.

```
const remainingTimeOption = myObject.data.options.find(option => option.key === "BSH.Common.Option.RemainingProgramTime");
console.log(remainingTimeOption.value);
console.log(remainingTimeOption.unit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myArray.data.options.find(x => x.key == 'BSH.Common.Option.RemainingProgramTime')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  I need to get more sleep, this was a stupid question with obvious answers, sorry.

Comment: Next time you should update your question instead of submitting a reply to your own question, as your reply falls under "Answers" which you do not provide here.